# Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be sequence of integers such that $\dots$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question:**
Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ be sequence of integers such that

1. $-1 \leq x_i \leq 2$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$.
2. $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = 19$
3. ${x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 + \dots + {x_n}^2 = 99$

Determine the minimum and maximum possible values of
$${x_1}^3 + {x_2}^3 + \dots + {x_n}^3$$

**Attempt:**
To simply the problem, the domain  $-1 \leq x_i \leq 2$ is simplified to integers $-1, 1, 2$ since $0$ is of no use other than elongate $n$ to $\infty$. Also pairs of both positive would be impossible since (2) above would overshoot $19$ to meet the requirements of (3). Thus we are left with the following options, $(-1, 1)$ and/or $(-1, 2)$. To determine the quantity/plausibility of each of our options, we determine the number of $-1$ and $1$ for $(-1, 1)$ and so on.

For (-1, 1), Let $x$ be the number of $-1$ and $y$ be the number of $1$:
$$x+y = 99; -x + y = 19$$
$$x = 40, y = 59$$

For (-1, 2), we have no integer solution, thus we are left with the $(-1, 1)$.

That being said, ${x_1}^3 + {x_2}^3 + \dots + {x_n}^3$, would be $(-1)^3*40 + 1*59 = 19$ for both maximum and minimum values.

Can someone check if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: What are these pairs?

Comment: @vadim123 possible values of $x_i$

Comment: Why can't the sequence contain all three values?

Comment: @aschepler crap, forgot that case.

Comment: I think it makes more sense now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to work with a rescaled version of the problem. Put $y_i=x_i+1$.

Then all the $y_i$s belong to the $[0,3]$ interval and:
$$\sum y_i = 19+n,\qquad \sum y_i^2 = 99+2\sum x_i+n = 137+n.$$

Due to the AM-QM inequality, we must have $n\geq 4$. Under such assumption, the convexity of $\sum x_i^3$ implies that the maximum is on the boundary (that is the intersection between a sphere and a cube), while the minimum can be found through Lagrange multipliers, for instance. The inequality between the cubic mean and the quadratic mean gives:
$$\sum y_i^3\geq n\left(1+\frac{137}{n}\right)^{3/2},$$
from which it follows that:
$$\sum x_i^3\geq n\left(1+\frac{137}{n}\right)^{3/2}-3(137+n)-3(19+n)-n.$$
However, the last inequality is non-trivial only for $n\leq 10$.